# I cannot get my query to pull all records from my product table

Tags: mysql

I need it to pull all products in the product table, It only seems to pull a record of a product if there is a corresponding data in the quick stock survey lines.

```
SELECT from_unixtime(j.job_datetime/1000+7200, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS tme,
  s.store_name,
  s.store_chain,
  dev.device_user_name,
  qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id,
  qss.quick_stock_survey_id,
  qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quantity,
  qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_is_outofstock,
  prd.product_description,
  prd.product_order,
  cat.category_name,
  product_status
FROM product AS prd
LEFT JOIN quick_stock_survey_lines AS qss_lines
  ON qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_product_id = prd.product_id
LEFT JOIN quick_stock_survey AS qss
  ON qss.quick_stock_survey_id = qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quick_stock_survey_id
LEFT JOIN job AS j
  ON j.job_id = qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id
LEFT JOIN store AS s 
  ON  j.job_store_id = s.store_id 
LEFT JOIN device_user AS dev
  ON dev.device_user_id = j.job_device_user_id
LEFT JOIN category AS cat
  ON cat.category_id = prd.product_default_category_id
WHERE dev.device_user_client_id = 173
  AND j.job_type = 6
  AND ((j.job_datetime/1000) BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-604800) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) 
ORDER BY prd.product_order, dev.device_user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the logic of the `WHERE` clause to the respective `ON` clause.  The reason for this is that your current `WHERE` clause is running the risk of prematurely filtering off entire records from your result set simply because a few of the many join conditions may not be matching.

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(j.job_datetime/1000+7200, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS tme,
    s.store_name,
    s.store_chain,
    dev.device_user_name,
    qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id,
    qss.quick_stock_survey_id,
    qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quantity,
    qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_is_outofstock,
    prd.product_description,
    prd.product_order,
    cat.category_name,
    product_status
FROM product as prd
LEFT JOIN quick_stock_survey_lines AS qss_lines
    ON qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_product_id = prd.product_id
LEFT JOIN quick_stock_survey AS qss
    ON qss.quick_stock_survey_id = qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quick_stock_survey_id
LEFT JOIN job AS j
    ON j.job_id = qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id AND
       j.job_type = 6 AND
       ((j.job_datetime/1000) BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-604800) AND
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
LEFT JOIN store AS s 
    ON j.job_store_id = s.store_id
LEFT JOIN device_user AS dev
    ON dev.device_user_id = j.job_device_user_id AND
       dev.device_user_client_id = 173
LEFT JOIN category AS cat
    ON cat.category_id = prd.product_default_category_id
ORDER BY
    prd.product_order,
    dev.device_user_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, I tried this but it seems to then pull all products and not just specific to the client ID in the clause

Comment: Then add sample data to your question.  Note that it's going to very hard for me to change my answer, because you have so many joins in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `WHERE` clause as it filter out the data and after this you will be able to pull all products

```
SELECT from_unixtime(j.job_datetime/1000+7200, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS tme,
s.store_name,
s.store_chain,
dev.device_user_name,
qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id,
qss.quick_stock_survey_id,
qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quantity,
qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_is_outofstock,
prd.product_description,
prd.product_order,
cat.category_name,
product_status
FROM product as prd
LEFT  JOIN quick_stock_survey_lines as qss_lines
On qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_product_id = prd.product_id
LEFT JOIN quick_stock_survey as qss
ON qss.quick_stock_survey_id =qss_lines.quick_stock_survey_lines_quick_stock_survey_id
LEFT JOIN job as j
On j.job_id = qss.quick_stock_survey_job_id
LEFT JOIN store as s 
On  j.job_store_id = s.store_id 
LEFT JOIN device_user as dev
On dev.device_user_id = j.job_device_user_id
LEFT JOIN category as cat
On cat.category_id = prd.product_default_category_id
Order BY prd.product_order, dev.device_user_name;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I get you reasoning but the problem here would then be it will not pull for my date range and also not for the specific ID, Maybe i should have been more clear, this query is to pull data for a report for a client of mine